# SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message could not be sent. Gmail security alert

Tags: php, yii2, smtp, phpmailer, mail-server

We are facing  an Error **SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.**!
while signup  And i paste the exact response of ajax call

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.{"success":true}
```

The success message clearly indicate that we don't have any error in code ?  Secondly  **Less secure option is also On**.
**and Here is my Code**

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
            $mail = new JPhpMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Port = 25;
            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = '*****@gmail.com';// $user->email
            $mail->Password = '********';// $user->pass
            $mail->SetFrom('******@gmail.com', '********');
                $mail->Subject = 'Inviting you ';
            $mail->MsgHTML($user->contactName.' '.$user->email.' '.$user->phone.' has signed Up & This is your password ' .$password);
              $mail->AddAddress($user->email, $user->contactName);
              $mail_send_flag=$mail->Send();
```

Note :
**May be this is reason of problem**  maybe this will help.

When I login in my gamil account and see these few email As my friend who is in other country and he try to login  from email account 
here is picture

[image]

Thanks in advance  for Your Response

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're running [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` so that you can see what the server is saying - it's probably saying something that's covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: @Synchro I am Agree With you brother you save my a lot of time 
if u post as answer i will accept it Respect

Comment: What I posted isn't really an answer - which is why I posted it as a comment. Your first reaction to any kind of problem like this is to check you're running the latest version, read the docs, then search stack overflow, and only then go to the effort of posting a question, since it's the slowest way to get an answer.

Comment: @Synchro Thanks  i am new in this field  This is the best advice for me,
Thanks Again Sir

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using port number 25.. Please use the port number 465 or 587. May be it will work.

Comment: Sure i will try and share my feedback soon  @eitBiz
Thanks

Comment: TLS mode will work on port 25, but 587 would be the usual choice.

Answer (score 1):

You must 587 for port, tls method using port 587 and ssl using port 465.
Try 587 in port number

Comment: Sure i will try and share my feedback soon  @Vahid Moghadam
Thanks